# Building And deploying app to MobileFirst using ANT script

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i have a eclipse with mobile first plugin installed. is it possible to build and deploy the app and adapters using ANT scripts to the mobile first server?..or do i need a standalone MobileFirst server installation(Mobile First with WAS liberty profile) to do this?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Eclipse with MobileFirst Studio, then you are not supposed to use ANT for building and deploying - you have the Eclipse UI for it.

You must not use the MobileFirst Studio for anything else other than development purposes.

Make sure you have bought MobileFirst Platform so that you could deploy it to a WAS/Liberty/Tomcat instance, where you can then also use Ant to deploy artifacts to the MobileFirst Server.

I suggest reading here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#SSHS8R_6.3.0/wl_welcome.html